# How call a method in a spring bean on web context initialization

Tags: spring, tomcat

I have a war file that includes the  following

**Spring Bean**

```
public class DataLoader {
   private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(DataLoader.class.getName());
   public void init() {
       log.info("DataLoader init called");
   }
}
```

**applicationContext.xml**

```
<bean id="dataLoader" class="com.example.DataLoader"
     init-method="init" lazy-init="false">
 </bean>
```

**web.xml**

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
   <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

I want the init method in the DataLoader to be called when I deploy the war file to a web container. However, it does not get called.

I thought that the init method would get called after the bean is initialized because of init-method="init" in the bean configuration, and that the bean would be initialized on deployment because of lazy-init="false".

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure your bean is being initialized at all?  You probably want to make your `DataLoader` class extend `InitializingBean`, and rename `init` to `afterPropertiesSet`.  The more modern way of doing this, however, would be to drop the XML configuration for the bean, and alter you class in this way:

```
@Component
public class DataLoader {
    private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(DataLoader.class.getName());

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        log.info("DataLoader init called");
    }
}
```